# Does the ideal gas law apply to a moving vehicle?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, aerodynamics, air, gas

If for example you have a car travelling along a road. There is obviously a high pressure region in front of the car, where the air is forced around the vehicle. Likewise, I understand that cars will leave a region of low pressure air directly behind them.

Air is described as being incompressible below mach 0.3. Therefore, this would suggest that the density of the air would be the same at the front of the car as it is behind it.

However, this would contradict the ideal gas law which suggests that for there to be a change in pressure in the air, there must also be a change in density.

Comment: So, when I use a bicycle tire pump I must be exceeding mach 0.3... otherwise the air would not enter the tire from the pump.

Comment: @SolarMike - Exactly, I totally agree. This was what confused me by the "air can be treated as incompressible below mach 0.3" statement. Personally, the ideal gas situation makes more sense to me, in the sense that I would imagine a moving car to have a low density region behind it. However, there is also a lot of information online about how gases can be treated as incompressible below mach 0.3. I was hoping someone could shed some light on how exactly this works.

Comment: Up to about 40mph, the power of the engine is used to overcome the rolling resistance of a car, after that the power has to overcome the aerodynamic forces which increase exponentially with speed... See a good explanation by James May here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LO0PgyPWE3o  after about 1 min 50 secs...

Comment: The description that air is incompressible below Mach 0.3 is a simplification that is used so that analysis of fluid flow can avoid considerations of gas laws. An example of the proper approach at a situation of gas flow is [here](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23740/force-applied-by-fan-under-inviscid-incompressible-flow/23772#23772).

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer Thanks for the explanation. So, does this mean that there would be a region of lower density air behind the vehicle?

Comment: Yes. The gas behind the vehicle is less compressed than the gas in front. When it is at the same temperature, the gas behind has a lower density.

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer - Thanks for this information. This was exactly what I thought initially. I am still somewhat confused though as to how this fits in with the fact that you can model air as incompressible below 0.3 mach, as surely this contradicts this?

Comment: I've posted an answer to move this out of comments.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* model a gas as incompressible. But, that does not mean that it **is** incompressible.

The difference between compressible and incompressible arises in how you treat a kinetic energy term in the Bernoulli equation. With incompressible fluids, the term can be determined directly because conservation of mass flow also means conservation of volumetric flow. With compressible fluids, the kinetic energy term must include considerations for changes in the pressure and temperature of the gas.

Consider [this reference](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23740/force-applied-by-fan-under-inviscid-incompressible-flow/23772#23772). You will see the term $mv((p_i/p_e) - 1)$. A statement of being below Mach 0.3 is equivalent to stating that you have a low velocity $v$. The kinetic energy term is negligible relative to the pressure drop term.

Alternatively, you can also assume that a gas is incompressible when the ratio of the initial and end pressure is near to unity. This will also remove the difference in kinetic energies front to back.

Answer (score 1):

"Incompressible" means different things in different contexts.

- In thermodynamics, an "incompressible substance" is one whose properties are completely insensitive to pressure. This is a good model for solids and liquids but not for gases.
- In fluid dynamics, "incompressible flow" means that the velocities present are not high enough to cause significant density changes.

The statement "air is incompressible below Mach 0.3" refers to incompressibility in the *fluid dynamical* sense; it means that, in air, velocities below Mach 0.3 are not capable of causing significant density changes. The statement does not imply that air is an incompressible substance; unless the temperature is very very low or the pressure is very very high, air is best modelled as an ideal gas and not an incompressible substance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So does this mean that a car (travelling below mach 0.3) is incapable of causing a significant density change to the air directly behind the car? i.e. the density of the air behind the car will not be significantly different to that of air at standard atmospheric pressure and temperature?

Comment: Correct. All of the properties will change *a bit* in the flow field around the car, but the changes in pressure are most relevant in fluid dynamics/aerodynamics. The pressure in front of a moving car is higher than that behind it, and the difference creates a force which contributes to drag ("pressure drag").

Comment: So are you saying that at low speeds i.e. below mach 0.3, this pressure differential between the front and rear of the vehicle will be very low, given the car is incapable of causing a significant change in density and therefore (using the ideal gas law) also incapable of causing a significant change in pressure?

Comment: We're getting far enough from the original question that I'm not longer sure. I believe that a car's wake perturbs both the pressure and the density (per the ideal gas law), but that aerodynamicists would think of the pressure change as significant (because a small pressure change can lead to a big drag) but the density change as insignificant (because it has little impact on the car or the way that the fluid dynamics is treated).

Comment: That makes sense. So, for example, the pressure (and density) differential may be only 1%, which would still be significant in terms of drag, but many would view this as insignificant in terms of a density variation?

Comment: Yes, that was my thinking.

Comment: @user1476176 The statements about gas flow are often not made with such subtle care. The statement that is more often made is "(Use the Bernoulli equation because) Air is (essentially) incompressible below Mach 0.3". Also, the density of an ideal gas is directly proportional to the pressure at constant temperature. Pressure is directly associated to drag force per area, even intuitively. By comparison, no one ever says ... "Mass density times absolute temperature times the gas law constant divided by the molar mass gives drag force per area".